# how to put an img into sql table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, image

I'm trying to put an img into my table

```
insert into product (img) 
SELECT '1', BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'product_test.jpeg', Single_Blob) as img
```

I have that so far but it comes up with an error #1064 telling me I have a syntax error
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: This question needs more information. You should put at least as much work into asking it as someone does who answers it. "Put an img into my table" -- the bits, a path, a URL? Which dialect of SQL? Which version? Can you copy and paste the error?

Comment: This is really more of an X/Y question because storing images directly in the database is not the best approach most of the time.

Comment: Your question is an ***X/Y*** question, which is (sort of) off-topic for Stack Overflow (too broad).

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend you to insert any image into your db tables. If you do it anyway, you will looe  remarkable performance you acquire from your current database, that means loss of speed and lots of useless data space.

I recommend you to upload your images to your website and insert their location into your tables.

here is more information about my suggestion: http://bit.ly/1rolVMX

Comment: Actually it might be _faster_ to store the blob in the database: http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525

Comment: Factually irrelevant and not answering the question. And totally ignorant of the potential databases - which mean that sometimes it is a VERY viable approach.

Comment: you should add the relevant code into your answer to support it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify both columns in your insert statement :

```
insert into product (theOthercolumnName, img) 
SELECT '1', BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'product_test.jpeg', Single_Blob) as img
```

Also make sure that the column definitions are matching to what you're inserting too